# How to avoid bug with navigator.popbackstack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, navhostcontroller

I have two screens, A and B in Master/Detail. B (Detail) has an actionbar on top with a back icon to go back to Master. However, I've noticed that if I doubletap the back icon, it goes back to A (as expected) and then the screen goes completely blank.

My current code to access screen B is as follows

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = ScreenRouter.ScreenA.route)
{
    composable(ScreenRouter.PokemonList.route) {
                PokedexList(showPokemonDetail = { myID ->
                navController.navigate(
                        route = ScreenRouter.ScreenB.createRoute(myID)
                    )
                })

            }

    composable(route = ScreenRouter.ScreenB.route) { backStackEntry ->
       val myID = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("id")
       requireNotNull(myID)    
       ScreenB(
          id = myID, 
          navigateUp = {navController.popBackStack()}
       )
    }
}
```

It feels like by the time I'm in Screen B, there are two screens loaded in memory. One popbackstack leads to Screen A. An additional popbackstack removes also that and leaves me in this blank "no-screen" situation.

How can I prevent this in a good practices way?

Comment: Seems like it is doing exactly what you told it to do - pop twice. What do you want it to do instead? Are you looking to ignore clicks when a transition to another screen is already in progress? Or exit the whole activity?

Comment: not exactly what I told it, since it's screen B the one to do "double popbackstack" when it should only be counted as one.

Comment: So it sounds like you want to handle the first click (when no transition is going on) differently from a second click (when the NavController has already started to transition to the new screen) and only have the first one actually pop?

Comment: Clicking that actionbar button on Screen B should go to the previous screen (Screen A in this case, but in the future it can come from different screens) no matter how many times it gets clicked. That's what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 2):

This is what's causing your problem:

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/backstack#handle-failure

> When the popBackStack() returns false, a subsequent call to
> NavController.getCurrentDestination() returns null. This means the app
> has popped the last destination off the back stack. In this case, the
> user sees only a blank screen.
>
> This can occur in the following cases:
>
> ```
> popBackStack() did not pop anything from the stack.
> popBackStack() did pop a destination off the back stack and the stack is now empty.
> ```

So you can try implementing logic that evaluates whether there is something available in the backstack to pop